# When to use maven multi module project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I was going to couple of blogs to get the basics of maven, in the mean time I was confused when I can use the multi module project. It will be great if the answer includes example.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that you have small modules that are dependent on each other and can be grouped together. Its not necessary that all sub-modules in a multi-module project be dependent on every other sub-module.

Lets consider you have multiple modules for an application (e.g a social networking application) that belong together. These modules can range from smaller modules like a client consumer module or a server module that will serve requests initiated by the client module, an ejb module that will hold your beans that are used by both the server and the client module and a deploy-able web module that would comprise of your front-end application  etc.

This is usually handled via a multi-module build which means all modules have the same version number, are bound together under a similar platform (a social networking application in our example) but can be accessed and used by other separately.

[image: Maven multi module iimage]

Comment: In the above pic I can see that there are several module which will do there job independently/dependently, but at the end I need a war application that depends on sample-services and sample-domain. So my question where the the source will be generated and how the packaging is done to generate the war file and how they will be linked?

Comment: You wish to assemble all modules into a single war file ?

Comment: yup, i wanted to generate a war file with all its dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Please check [How to assemble multimodule maven project into one WAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897114/how-to-assemble-multimodule-maven-project-into-one-war) to know how to package a multi module project in a war file. also, you can check maven official site on [Introduction to pom file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)